# How can I draw a iregular shape of div and apply a shadow to it?

Tags: html, css

What I want to draw is more or less like below, in which the div's size is dynamic (depend on screen size and content in it), and two circle's size is static (in px).

Is there a better way to draw this with shadow?

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.left,
.right {
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 0px 0px red);
  left: -10px;
  top: 50%;
}

.right {
  left: 197px;
  filter: drop-shadow(-5px 0px 1px red);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

[Js Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v8590bzy/#embed)

Update: below is the actual element that I want to style, in which the `box-shadow` is been cut by circles.

[image: actual element(s) to be styled]

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like below using radial-gradient as background:

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 10px at left ,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) left,
    radial-gradient(circle 10px at right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) right;
  background-size:51% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 4px red);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Using mask if you want a random background:

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  border-radius:10px;
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 4px red);
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:linear-gradient(60deg,lightgreen,lightblue); /* OR url() */
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle 10px at left ,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) left,
    radial-gradient(circle 10px at right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) right;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

In order to consider dynamic content you can do like below:

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 4px red);
}

.box>div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  padding:10px;
}
.box>div:first-child {
}

.box div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-mask: 
    radial-gradient(circle 10px at var(--p, bottom) left, transparent 98%, #fff 100%) left,
    radial-gradient(circle 10px at var(--p, bottom) right, transparent 98%, #fff 100%) right;
  -webkit-mask-size: 51% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: grey;
}

.box div:last-child::before {
  --p: top;
  border-top:2px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lectus leo, tincidunt at justo malesuada, consectetur sollicitudin nulla. Integer quis condimentum ipsum. Morbi hendrerit porttitor turpis, ac fringilla ipsum posuere vel. Suspendisse non interdum lorem, id iaculis augue. </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lectus leo, tincidunt</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lectus leo, tincidunt</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lectus leo, tincidunt , tincidunt at justo malesuada, consectetur sollicitudin nulla. Integer quis condimentum ipsum. Morbi hendrerit </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does two half-circles must be at the middle of the sides? Actually, in my case, their position will depend on contents of top and bottom half card, which are dynamic either.

Comment: @GlacJAY it can be based on content. Edit your question to detail this and I will edit my answer